# minecraft forge gradle "runClient" Exception

Tags: gradle, minecraft, minecraft-forge

I should install minecraft forge.
I write gradle command.

```
gradlew setupDecompWorkspace
gradlew eclipse
```

This command is run well.

But next command is not working

```
gradlew runClient
```

This is exception of  command.

```
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException: null
  at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_242]
  at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
 ~[?:1.8.0_242]
  at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
 ~[?:1.8.0_242]
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[?:1.8.0_242]
  at net.minecraft.launchwrapper.Launch.launch(Launch.java:135) [launchwrapper-1.12.jar:?]
  at net.minecraft.launchwrapper.Launch.main(Launch.java:28) [launchwrapper-1.12.jar:?]
  at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_242]
  at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
 ~[?:1.8.0_242]
  at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
 ~[?:1.8.0_242]
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[?:1.8.0_242]
  at net.minecraftforge.gradle.GradleStartCommon.launch(GradleStartCommon.java:97)
 [start/:?]
  at GradleStart.main(GradleStart.java:25) [start/:?]
Caused by: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
  at net.minecraft.client.Minecraft.getSystemTime(Minecraft.java:3159)
 ~[Minecraft.class:?]
  at net.minecraft.client.main.Main.main(Main.java:42) ~[Main.class:?]
   ... 12 more
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:1847) ~[?:1.8.0_242]
  at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Runtime.java:871) ~[?:1.8.0_242]
  at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:1124) ~[?:1.8.0_242]
  at org.lwjgl.Sys$1.run(Sys.java:72) ~[lwjgl-2.9.4-nightly-20150209.jar:?]
  at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_242]
  at org.lwjgl.Sys.doLoadLibrary(Sys.java:66) ~[lwjgl-2.9.4-nightly-20150209.jar:?]
  at org.lwjgl.Sys.loadLibrary(Sys.java:87) ~[lwjgl-2.9.4-nightly-20150209.jar:?]
  at org.lwjgl.Sys.<clinit>(Sys.java:117) ~[lwjgl-2.9.4-nightly-20150209.jar:?]
  at net.minecraft.client.Minecraft.getSystemTime(Minecraft.java:3159)
 ~[Minecraft.class:?]
  at net.minecraft.client.main.Main.main(Main.java:42) ~[Main.class:?]
  ... 12 more
Exception in thread "main" [07:55:11] [main/INFO] [STDERR]: [java.lang.ThreadGroup:uncaughtException:1052]:
 java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
[07:55:11] [main/INFO] [STDERR]: [java.lang.ThreadGroup:uncaughtException:1052]:        at
 sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
[07:55:11] [main/INFO] [STDERR]: [java.lang.ThreadGroup:uncaughtException:1052]:
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    [07:55:11] [main/INFO] [STDERR]: [java.lang.ThreadGroup:uncaughtException:1052]:        at
 sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
     [07:55:11] [main/INFO] [STDERR]: [java.lang.ThreadGroup:uncaughtException:1052]:        at
 java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
     [07:55:11] [main/INFO] [STDERR]: [java.lang.ThreadGroup:uncaughtException:1052]:        at
net.minecraftforge.gradle.GradleStartCommon.launch(GradleStartCommon.java:97)
     [07:55:11] [main/INFO] [STDERR]: [java.lang.ThreadGroup:uncaughtException:1052]:        at
 GradleStart.main(GradleStart.java:25)
     [07:55:11] [main/INFO] [STDERR]: [java.lang.ThreadGroup:uncaughtException:1061]: Caused by:
 net.minecraftforge.fml.relauncher.FMLSecurityManager$ExitTrappedException
     [07:55:11] [main/INFO] [STDERR]: [java.lang.ThreadGroup:uncaughtException:1061]:        at
 net.minecraftforge.fml.relauncher.FMLSecurityManager.checkPermission(FMLSecurityManager.java:49)
     [07:55:11] [main/INFO] [STDERR]: [java.lang.ThreadGroup:uncaughtException:1061]:        at
 java.lang.SecurityManager.checkExit(SecurityManager.java:761)
     [07:55:11] [main/INFO] [STDERR]: [java.lang.ThreadGroup:uncaughtException:1061]:        at
 java.lang.Runtime.exit(Runtime.java:108)
     [07:55:11] [main/INFO] [STDERR]: [java.lang.ThreadGroup:uncaughtException:1061]:        at
 java.lang.System.exit(System.java:973)
     [07:55:11] [main/INFO] [STDERR]: [java.lang.ThreadGroup:uncaughtException:1061]:        at
 net.minecraft.launchwrapper.Launch.launch(Launch.java:138)
     [07:55:11] [main/INFO] [STDERR]: [java.lang.ThreadGroup:uncaughtException:1061]:        at
 net.minecraft.launchwrapper.Launch.main(Launch.java:28)
     [07:55:11] [main/INFO] [STDERR]: [java.lang.ThreadGroup:uncaughtException:1061]:        ... 6 more
     :runClient FAILED
     
     FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
     
     * What went wrong:
     Execution failed for task ':runClient'.
     > Process 'command 'C:\Program Files\ojdkbuild\java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.242-1\bin\java.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 1
     
     * Try:
     Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
     
     BUILD FAILED
     
     Total time: 9.208 secs

What can I do??

Also gradlew build is well.
```

Comment: This problem originated with openJDK.

Answer (score 0):

If you are modding with ForgeGradle 3, you can runClient now 
because ForgeGradle 3 is updated.

If you aren't modding with ForgeGradle 3.x, there is nothing you can 
with official ForgeGradle. Forge developer group never fix it. 
(see https://github.com/MinecraftForge/ForgeGradle/issues/652)

You can use fork of ForgeGradle or make fork of ForgeGradle.

I made fork of ForgeGradle [2.3](https://github.com/anatawa12/ForgeGradle-2.3) 
and [1.2](https://github.com/anatawa12/ForgeGradle-1.2) so you able to use them. 
(if there is question about my forks, please make issue in them.)
If you're using ForgeGradle which is not 2.3 or 1.2 or If you want not to use my fork, 
you can make fork of ForgeGradle.

### why this is occurred and what should you change in your fork

#### why this is occurred

The reason code of this crash is `hackNatives()` function in `GradleStart`. 
the `hackNatives` function sets `ClassLoader.sys_paths` `null` 
to reset `ClassLoader.usr_paths`.

Until 8u242, `ClassLoader.loadLibrary` checks whether `sys_paths` is `null` and 
reset `sys_paths` and `usr_paths` if `sys_paths` is `null`.

But since 8u242, `sys_paths` and `usr_paths` are initialized when start the JVM 
and `ClassLoader.loadLibrary` never check whether `sys_paths` is `null`. 
(see http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8u/jdk8u/jdk/rev/1d666f78532a/)

#### what should you change in your fork

We have to rewrite in `hackNatives()` in `GradleStart` class, there is 
in resources directory.
To reset `usr_paths`, execute `usr_paths = initializePath("java.library.path")` 
with reflection in `hackNatives()`. 
(you can refer hackNatives in minecraft forge 1.15.x userdev: 
[LaunchTesting.java#L126](https://github.com/MinecraftForge/MinecraftForge/blob/9d8817b5db53db7f92ac1346b1a64523dc36dfbe/src/userdev/java/net/minecraftforge/userdev/LaunchTesting.java#L126))